# Running the BM3D Denoising Algorithm in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv, denoising

I am looking for a strong baseline in image denoising and therefore wanted to have the [BM3D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block-matching_and_3D_filtering) algorithm in my benchmark.

These 2 python implementations:

- https://github.com/ericmjonas/pybm3d
- https://github.com/liuhuang31/BM3D-Denoise

have been unmaintained for a long time (and the second one is documented in what I think is chinese). I have experimented a bit with the first one without satisfactory results (see https://github.com/ericmjonas/pybm3d/issues/11 with non satisfactory fixes like clipping).

This package : https://pypi.org/project/bm3d/#description , doesn't have a documentation or source code easily findable.

Then I found this: https://docs.opencv.org/master/de/daa/group__xphoto.html#ga2fc5a9661c1338a823fb3290673a880d, in the docs of opencv but there is no indication as to how to use it and no examples in python. I saw this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41853606/opencv-how-to-properly-call-bm3ddenoising) but it's for a C++ implementation and I don't know how it would translate in Python because I am not familiar at all with opencv.

Comment: Have you found something?

Comment: @David see the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I resorted to was using the [PyPI package](https://pypi.org/project/bm3d/), which is advertised here: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~foi/GCF-BM3D/index.html#ref_software.

I dug a bit in the source code, and found that I could perform BM3D, in the following fashion:

```
import bm3d

denoised_image = bm3d.bm3d(image_noisy, sigma_psd=30/255, stage_arg=bm3d.BM3DStages.HARD_THRESHOLDING)
```

There are also some examples in the library's [source code download](https://pypi.org/project/bm3d/#files).

I installed `bm3d` using `pip` (`pip install bm3d`) and needed OpenBlas (`sudo apt-get install libopenblas-dev`).

Comment: While this solution works, it doesn't implement the full bm3d algorithm, which is more powerful when used with `stage_arg=bm3d.BM3DStages.ALL_STAGES`. It is however twice slower with all stages.

Comment: Just as a confirmation, this method allows me to reproduce the results of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.02452.pdf (Table 1) and https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.03981.pdf (Table 2) on the [BSD68 dataset](https://github.com/cszn/DnCNN/tree/master/testsets/BSD68) in terms of PSNR.

Comment: You can find an example of how I implemented it in those lines: https://github.com/zaccharieramzi/understanding-unets/blob/master/learning_wavelets/utils/metrics.py#L58-L62

Comment: i used the same implementation but it doesn't denoise at all.

Comment: @Rima You could open a new question with a minimal working example in order to let us help you properly

Comment: i did it now, thanks. Looking for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the PyPI package for bm3d, you can use ffmpeg and run the bm3d filter as an OS command-

```
command="ffmpeg -i "+input_image_path+" -filter_complex bm3d=sigma=30/255:block=4:bstep=2:group=1:hdthr=10000:estim=basic /path/to/output/directory/output.png"    
os.system(command)
```

This takes lesser computation time.