# Problem with running BM3D implementation in Python

Tags: image-processing, image-restoration

I found about one of the BM3D implementation in Python through this [post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/62098/running-the-bm3d-denoising-algorithm-in-python) and tried to use the same, however, I don't see any difference after using the algorithm.

Here is a small snippet of my code,

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
from numpy import pad
from math import log10, sqrt
from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity as ssim
import timeit
import random
from skimage.restoration import denoise_tv_chambolle
import bm3d
from skimage import data


img = data.camera()
cv2.imshow("original image", img)
row, col = img.shape
cv2.waitKey(0)

def add_gaussian_noise(mu, row, col, sigma, img):
    noise = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, (row, col))
    noise = noise.reshape(row, col)
    img = img + noise
    return img
def bm3d_filter(img_noisy, sigma_psd):
    img_filt = bm3d.bm3d(img_noisy, sigma_psd, stage_arg=bm3d.BM3DStages.ALL_STAGES)
    return img_filt
sigma_psd = 10/255
img_noisy_gaussian = add_gaussian_noise(0,row, col, sigma, img)
img_bm3d = bm3d_filter(img_noisy_gaussian, sigma_psd)
img_bm3d = np.clip(img_bm3d, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)

cv2.imshow("bm3d", img_bm3d)
def PSNR(original, filtered):
    mse = np.mean((original - filtered) ** 2)
    if(mse == 0):  # MSE is zero means no noise is present in the signal .
                  # Therefore PSNR have no importance.
        return 100
    max_pixel = 255.0
    psnr = 20 * log10(max_pixel / sqrt(mse))
    return psnr
  
def SSIM(img, img_noise, img_filter):
    ssim_noise = ssim(img, img_noise, data_range=img_noise.max() - img_noise.min())
    ssim_none = ssim(img, img, data_range=img.max() - img.min())
    ssim_filter = ssim(img, img_filter, data_range = img_filter.max() - img_filter.min())
    return ssim_noise, ssim_none, ssim_filter
       
def processing_time(func):
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    func
    stop = timeit.default_timer()

    return stop-start

value = PSNR(img_bm3d, img.astype(np.uint8))
print(f"PSNR value is {value} dB")
ssim_noise, ssim_none, ssim_filter = SSIM(img,img_noisy_gaussian, img_bm3d)
print(f"SSIM for original image is {ssim_none}")
print(f"SSIM for noisy image is {ssim_noise}")
print(f"SSIM for filtered image is {ssim_filter}")
```

No matter what I change the value of sigma_psd, I see no difference between the noisy and filtered image.

Output: [image: output image]

```
PSNR value is 29.34133102[![output][3]][3]2381176 dB
SSIM for original image is 1.0
SSIM for noisy image is 0.46349580507581284
SSIM for filtered image is 0.4705020406258775
```

Did i understand the use wrong? I ran the matlab version of the implementation with the demo example provided by the author, nonetheless, it works fine.

Could someone help me with it?

Comment: I think it's important that in your minimal example you give us something that is runnable as is, so that we can debug easily. Here for example we do not know how you load the image, and I think this might be key since the dynamic range might be the issue here.

Comment: I have just imported using cv2.imread(), i have edited my code. Hope that helps.

Comment: Could you redo the example but this time using an image we all have access to? for example using scikit-image's general purpose images : https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/data/plot_general.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-data-plot-general-py

Comment: sorry. I completely forgot that the image is in my local folder. Now i have used  a test image and edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing with your code I understood that the error was as I suggested the dynamic range of your image and noisy image:

- make sure to divide the image by 255: `img = img / 255`
- clip the values between 0 and 1 after adding the noise: `img_noisy_gaussian = np.clip(img_noisy_gaussian, 0, 1)`, otherwise you can't use `bm3d.BM3DStages.ALL_STAGES` (although `bm3d.BM3DStages.HARD_THRESHOLDING` works for some reason).

Make sure you also get rid of `img_bm3d = np.clip(img_bm3d, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)`.

Ultimately the code now becomes:

````py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
from numpy import pad
from math import log10, sqrt
from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity as ssim
import timeit
import random
from skimage.restoration import denoise_tv_chambolle
import bm3d
from skimage import data


img = data.camera()
img = img / 255
cv2.imshow("original image", (img*255).astype(np.uint8))
row, col = img.shape
cv2.waitKey(0)

def add_gaussian_noise(mu, row, col, sigma, img):
    noise = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, (row, col))
    noise = noise.reshape(row, col)
    img = img + noise
    return img
def bm3d_filter(img_noisy, sigma_psd):
    img_filt = bm3d.bm3d(img_noisy, sigma_psd, stage_arg=bm3d.BM3DStages.ALL_STAGES)
    return img_filt
sigma_psd = 10/255
img_noisy_gaussian = add_gaussian_noise(0,row, col, sigma, img)
img_noisy_gaussian = np.clip(img_noisy_gaussian, 0, 1)
img_bm3d = bm3d_filter(img_noisy_gaussian, sigma_psd)

cv2.imshow("bm3d", (img_bm3d*255).astype(np.uint8))
def PSNR(original, filtered):
    mse = np.mean((original - filtered) ** 2)
    if(mse == 0):  # MSE is zero means no noise is present in the signal .
                  # Therefore PSNR have no importance.
        return 100
    max_pixel = 255.0
    psnr = 20 * log10(max_pixel / sqrt(mse))
    return psnr
  
def SSIM(img, img_noise, img_filter):
    ssim_noise = ssim(img, img_noise, data_range=img_noise.max() - img_noise.min())
    ssim_none = ssim(img, img, data_range=img.max() - img.min())
    ssim_filter = ssim(img, img_filter, data_range = img_filter.max() - img_filter.min())
    return ssim_noise, ssim_none, ssim_filter
       
def processing_time(func):
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    func
    stop = timeit.default_timer()

    return stop-start

value = PSNR(img_bm3d, img.astype(np.uint8))
print(f"PSNR value is {value} dB")
ssim_noise, ssim_none, ssim_filter = SSIM(img,img_noisy_gaussian, img_bm3d)
print(f"SSIM for original image is {ssim_none}")
print(f"SSIM for noisy image is {ssim_noise}")
print(f"SSIM for filtered image is {ssim_filter}")
```
````

Comment: could you explain why are we normalising by 255 and clipping between [0,1]? I clipped directly between [0,255]. Also when i do as you suggested, first normalised ,and clip the noisy image between 0 to 1, and not use (astype(np.uint8)), it gived me a random white noise, like this, https://imgur.com/a/YECXAvY. since it's in decimal, i cannot use np.uint8, i tried with np.float32, it gave me the same image as i linked above.

Comment: and by Hard thresholding, do you mean with images clipped between 0 to 255? I tried doing that with no success.

Comment: So when you load an image, its dynamic range is between 0 and 255, this implementation expects images between 0 and 1. So I first normalize the image by dividing by 255, which makes it between 0 and 1, But then when I add noise, the image might have values slightly above 1 or below 0, which is why I am then clipping

Comment: I updated my answer to give you the code to run, which should give the correct images when visualizing with opencv.
By hard thresholding I just meant changing the way you call the bm3d implementation, see my updated answer.

Comment: ok but like I said, after cliiping between 0 to 1, i get the image that I linked before.

Comment: yes it's just a question of visualization, opencv expects an image between 0 and 255 in uint8 : you just have to alternate between the 2

Comment: ok i think the reason that the code is not working is because of the gaussian noise range. and the clipped image has mostly either 0 or 1 and few float value between 0-1. i will try to fix this first and let you know.

Comment: so i did this normalization of image not for the original one, but the nosiy image (i.e. /255) and it worked because when i did normalization to the original, my gaussian noise whose sigma was greater than 1 was causing problem. Thank you for pointing out the mistake that the bm3d works for imae clipped between 0 to 1.